# AWS EKS - IRSA how SDK is updated with credential provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-eks

I was going through this blog from AWS for creating a service account for a EKS pod to assume a IAM role .

blog - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/

In the below paragraph they have summarised how the entire flow works

> The final step necessary is that the pod, via its service account, assumes the IAM role. This works as follows: OIDC federation allows the user to assume IAM roles with the Secure Token Service (STS), effectively receiving a JSON Web Token (JWT) via an OAuth2 flow that can be used to assume an IAM role with an OIDC provider. In Kubernetes we then use projected service account tokens, which are valid OIDC JWTs, giving each pod a cryptographically-signed token which can be verified by STS against the OIDC provider for establishing identity. The AWS SDKs have been updated with a new credential provider that calls sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, exchanging the Kubernetes-issued OIDC token for AWS role credentials.

In the above text i am not able to understand this

> The AWS SDKs have been updated with a new credential provider .

So how will the SDK get updated ? - will it get updated automatically ?